# Parallax-ImageScroll and angularJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

i would like to use Parallax-ImageScrol jquery plug-in with angularJS.

i have create a directive for change the data-image value.

but the image never load

[Parallax-image plug'in](https://github.com/pederan/Parallax-ImageScroll)

```
angular.module('parallaxApp')
.controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {
    console.log(document.location);
    $http({
    method: 'GET',
    url: 'scripts/models/articles.json'
    })
    .success(function(data) {
    $scope.articles = data.article;
    $scope.onglets = data.onglet;
    $scope.footers = data.footer;
    });

})
.directive('myDataImage', function() {
    return {
        // Restrict it to be an attribute in this case
        restrict: 'A',
        // responsible for registering DOM listeners as well as updating the DOM
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            attrs.$set('image', scope.article.imagebackground);
    };
});





<div id="section">
<div ng-repeat="article in articles">
    <div my-data-image data-image="images/1.jpg" data-width="1600" data-height="900" data-extra-height="50" class="img-holder"></div>
         <section>
            <article class="section_main">
                <h1>{{article.titre}}</h1>
                <p>{{article.article}}</p>
            </article>
            <img ng-src={{article.image}} alt={{article.image-alt}}>
            <div class="scroll">
                <a data-scroll data-speed="1000" data-easing="easeInOutCubic"  href=".ancre1">
                    <img ng-src={{article.ancre}} alt={{article.ancre-alt}}>
                </a>
             </div>
        </section>
</div>
```

### thx for your help

Answer (score 1):

I have had your problem... I am solved initializing parallax inside the directive... before `link:` add

```
compile: function (element, attrs) {
    if (attrs.image !== undefined) {
        $(element).parallax({ imageSrc: attrs.image });
    }
},
```

where `attrs.image` exists because you are using the attribute `data-image`